# How to obtain rows from the MySQL database by a few filters?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have two tables in the MySQL database, see the database structure bellow:

```
tbl_product
id
1
2
3

tbl_product_filter
id | product_id | product_filter_value
1    1            1
2    1            2
3    1            3
4    2            1
5    2            2
6    3            1
```

How can I obtain the products which have only the value of the field `product_filter_value` **1** and **2**?

Answer (score 1):

Using Sub-queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_product
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM tbl_product_filter
    WHERE product_filter_value IN (1, 2)
)
```

Using Joins (this query might display one product multiple times):

```
SELECT tbl_product.*
FROM tbl_product
INNER JOIN tbl_product_filter ON tbl_product.id = tbl_product_filter.product_id
WHERE product_filter_value IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but these queries will be hard. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Hard? You're kidding me :) You really need to get the hang of joins and sub-queries.

Comment: Imagine that you have a table with 500,000 rows. See `EXPLAIN` and the time of execution.

Comment: Optimizing a query is another issue. You can post that as a separate question. But make sure that you have done the basics right (adding the necessary indexes for example and replacing `SELECT *` with `SELECT <only the columns you need>`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_product.*
FROM tbl_product_filter
INNER JOIN tbl_product USING (product_id)
WHERE product_filter_value IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY tbl_product_filter.product_id
```